# Can not copy files from old CD's into new system

Tags: data-recovery, file-transfer

I am trying to access some very old CD's I have (8+ years)

When inserting into my current OS (Windows 7) I can see the files, and I can also browse the folders.

The problem starts when I want to copy the files, or even create an ISO of the CD.

Using regular Copy - I get the error: "Can’t Read From the Source File or Disk"

When using TeraCopy - I get several errors:
[image]

Any idea how to solve/check what I can do ?

Is there a way to overcome bad sectors on CD's?

This happens with 2 CD's already, and I am tested my CD/DVD reader - it's working fine.

Comment: CDs will degrade over time, and the cheaper the CD, the faster they will degrade.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_rot ... don't assume that 8 years is too short.  All that said, even if you manage to copy the disc using a utility, what are you going to do with the corrupted data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Read Old DVDs?](http://superuser.com/questions/579373/how-to-read-old-dvds)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I copy files from a scratched CD/DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/508679/how-can-i-copy-files-from-a-scratched-cd-dvd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](https://roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29&Action=NewOSID), which attempts to copy every sector on a CD and skips over the bad ones.